# Groovy cannot implement Java interfaces which use inheritence and generics

Tags: java, groovy

I am working with a Java package which defines some generic interfaces. I would like to implement these interfaces with Groovy classes in a separate project. The Groovy compiler chokes and reports that I have not implemented the interface. The Java equivalent of the Groovy code works fine.

I've accepted that the Groovy compiler will not support what I'm trying to do so I'll find another way but I would still like to know why it's failing.

I have an example Maven project which demonstrates this problem on Github https://github.com/gilday/groovy-java-generics

Comment: What version of groovy? What's the actual exception?

Comment: Groovy 2.0.6 (in the pom). Compiler says "Can't have an abstract method in a non-abstract class. The class org.ozoneplatform.example.
UserRepositoryImpl' must be declared abstract or the method java.lang.Object getById(java.lang.Object)' must be implemented."

Comment: The compiler says my interface is "java.lang.Object getById(java.lang.Object)", but the return type should be "User" and the parameter type should be "Integer". I suspect Groovy may be stripping the type information somewhere as mentioned in the implementation note on this page http://groovy.codehaus.org/Generics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for certain, but it may be that the Java stubs for Groovy are not being generated properly.  You can try using the `groovy-eclipse-compiler` instead.  See here:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven